# What is the best approach for CCSpriteBatchNode and texture sheets in a Cocos2D game scene 

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, textures, ccsprite, frame-rate

I am modifying some tutorials I found on [Learn Cococs2D](http://www.apress.com/9781430233039/) and found that whenver I use more than one CCSpriteBatchNode in one class the frame rate drops.

Reading a bit around I understood that one CCSpriteBatchNode can accept only 1 texture sheet at a time and this poses some limitations on the level design (sprite sheet can be max 2048x2048 pixels [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549266/when-to-use-ccspritebatchnode)). Although there are some extensions that seem to overcome this limitaton (which I haven't yet dared to try) [CCBigImage](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/master/Extensions/CCBigImage).

I am trying to following the one file approach and load all my images in one CCSpriteFrameCache but I haven't found much on [programming guides](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:best_practices) about this.

In the ShootEmUp example of [1](http://www.apress.com/9781430233039/) the approach is to have a CCSpriteBatchNode in ParallaxNode as well as in other classes such as EnemyCache (find source on folder Chapter 8 on link [book source code link](http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/640/))

Although I have researched a bit on the cocos2d-iphone.org forums and found the following topic where a **moderator suggests to add only one instance of  CCSpriteBatchNode to the root layer** [forum topic](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/16827).

**I am now a bit confused**. The one thing I noticed is that following the [1](http://www.apress.com/9781430233039/) approach (multiple instances) the frame rate is not optimal. Have you similar experiences and how do you tackle this?

**Multiple CCSpriteBatchNode or not? 
One texture sheet per level or multiple?**

Thanks a lot for reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your issue with frame rate is due to multiple CCSpriteBatchNode's...  I have used more then one CCSpriteBatchNode in a class and I doubt this is the issue.  You can only have one CCSpriteFrameCache though.  You might need to post some code to get to the bottom of the issue

Comment: Sure I will post some code later today. I tried to implement what said above (one shared instance of CCSpriteBatchNode) but is kind of strange as on the simulator it runs at about 20fps and on my 4th gen iPod at about 58fps. I want to finish some testing before posting code. In the meanwhile, you said that you can have only one CCSpriteFrameCache and yes CCSpriteBatchNode? Have you read the post in the forum topic? Why did they say that? (I am just trying to understand..) Thanks a lot for the answer :)

Comment: I have accepted the answer only now as It took me some time to understand the role of CCSpriteFrameCache and CCSpriteBatchNode, I found a very useful guide here which helps as well: http://allseeing-i.com/Performance-tips-for-Cocos2d-for-iPhone